# Export data from Array to *.csv without curly brackets

Tags: export, list-manipulation, csv-format

I have a couple of *.csv files containing data from several experiments. From those, two columns shall be extracted each, to form a new list. This process shall be automated to collect all the data from all experiments of one series. For this I try to use an indexed variable a[i]. With Transpose and Array the desired list is created. But when I try to export my test case to a *.csv it contains those curly brackets and quotation marks (the first two lines contain strings). Within this forum a number of people suggested to use Flatten to get rid of the unwanted characters. This works but completely destroys the structure of the table, which I want to keep.

When I use Join on my testcase there are no brackets or quotation marks in the *.csv. But as far as I understand the indexed variables are better for my task since the number of experiments within the different series will change. This assumption is based on answers of the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783760/how-do-i-save-multiple-variables-with-an-iterated-name-in-mathematica

I suppose it might be "just" an issue with the data format. Because it looks like Mathematica is exporting the list instead of the values within the list itself. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to fix it.

Thank you in advance!

--Edit 1--

Here is a code example of my problem. I hope this helps better understanding the problem.

I'm importing the *.csv files to the indexed varibale, using colums 1 and 4.

```
heatcombarrayex[1] =
    Part[
        Import[
            TemplateApply[NotebookDirectory[] <> StringTemplate[
                newfilename <> "_``"][ToString[1] <> "-" <> ToString[1]]] <> 
                "\\" <> TemplateApply[StringTemplate[
                newfilename <> "``"][ToString[1] <> "-" <> ToString[1]]] <> 
                "_devc.csv"], 
    All, {1, 4}];
```

Then I use Array to show all the entries of the indexed variable. For my testcase I use two entries.

```
heatcombarrayoutex = Transpose[Array[heatcombarrayex, 2]];
```

Then the data is exported to a *.csv again.

```
Export[TemplateApply[
  NotebookDirectory[] <> 
   "heatcombarrayex.csv"], heatcombarrayoutex, "CSV"]
```

This shows the first four lines of the result (Also I realised that I forget to mention that the second column is also wrapped in qoutation marks.):

`{s", "kW/kg"}","{"s", "kW/kg"}"
{Time", "hrrpum"}","{"Time", "hrrpum"}"
{0., 0.},"{0., 0.}"
{4.21, 0.033500582},"{4.21, 0.041624561}"`

And this is how it should look like:

`s,kW/kg,s,kW/kg
Time,hrrpum,Time,hrrpum
0.,0.,0.,0.
4.21,0.033500582,4.21,0.041624561`

So the question is: How to get rid of those extra characters?

-- Edit 2 --

For the the test case I use two data files (which can be found via the added link). But I only posted the code to import file number one, since the code for the following is basically the same, just the number changes.

In Mathematica the `heatcombarrayoutex` looks like this:
`{{{"s", "kW/kg"}, {"s", "kW/kg"}}, {{"Time", "hrrpum"}, {"Time", 
   "hrrpum"}}, {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}, {{4.21, 0.0335006}, {4.21, 
   0.0416246}}, ...995..., {{4200., 0.}, {4200., 0.}}}`

I have two example files included for importing, which can be found following this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4kM2FTAynNCfmdNY2tIak5xcEI4Y2hUWE92WEw2UjZxb0JOLTJvT1l4VnZ6RlhyTjgyZzQ)

Comment: Do you have any code and data which illustrates your problem ?

Comment: Yes, I have some code added. I apologise that I forgot to put it there when I posted my issue.

Comment: In your result you have `{s", "kW/kg"}"` and `{Time", "hrrpum"}"`, these seem to have unbalanced quotes, is that intentional? A full example with input, code and in error output, plus desired output, would help.

Comment: No, this is not intentional, Mathematica somehow "made this up". This is why I believe there might be an issue with the data format. I suppose I need to tell Array something about the data format otherwise it might use some default which leads to this issue. The input file structure is like the "how it should look like"-example. Also Join produces the output in the right way.

Comment: To work out what went wrong it will be easier to have a full path from input data , through code, to output

Comment: @image_doctor: I suppose I do not really understand your question, because to me it looks like all the information you request is already given. Up to now I do nothing more then importing *.csv, take specific columns out of them and export them combined in a new *.csv. The first code example shows the import with the real folder structure. The second shows the processing and the third shows the export.If one opens the exported *.csv one see's the information given in the fourth example. The fifth example shows how it should look like when one opens the exported *.csv. The imported *.csv ...

Comment: ... look like the fifth example, too. Just they have more columns. Could you try to explain my what you are missing, I do not really get it. I have to say that I'm new to this forum and Mathematica, too. maybe there is some information I'm missing for writing a proper question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: One further remark: The folder structure is the following: One folder contains the Mathematica notebook and the folder of the data of the different experiments. So mathematica needs to go from ist own position one layer down in the folder structure to get the input (see code exaple 1) and the exported file is stored in the folder with the notebook.

Comment: You will probably get the best responses if people can take the sample code you provide, run it and reproduce the problem you are having. The questions editor contains formatting options for code so that people can just cut and paste what you supply straight into Mathematica and run it. Perhaps the problem here is with the input data, the code or some interaction between them, without sample input, it's hard to say at present.

Comment: Have you also defined `heatcombarrayex[2]`?  Otherwise I don't understand what you are doing with `Array`.  In any case show what `heatcombarrayoutex` looks like in mathematica.

Comment: There are many people here who will answer your question, if you give them the information they need :)

Comment: @image_doctor: Thank you for your help! I obviously misunderstood the "indent code by 4 spaces" part. Also I'm aware that a lot of people try to help, I just need to learn to provide the right information and not overload the post at the same time. Now it is really clunky, I think I should rewrite the whole post. :)

Comment: @george2079: Yes I do define the second entry, but since the code is nearly identical I did not write it explicitly. Now I added a remark within the second edit. Also how the output looks like in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer using a small amount of the two example data files you supplied.

Read the first 4 lines of each file:

```
 h = Import[#][[1 ;; 4, {1, 4}]] & /@ FileNames["/SampleData/Heat*"];
```

Transpose, flatten and export the data:

```
Export["/SampleData/heatcombarrayex.csv", Flatten/@Transpose@h]
```

The issue you were having is that when you transpose your data, you have nested lists which are represented in CSV format in bracketed form.

> {{{"s", "kW/kg"}, {"s", "kW/kg"}}, 
>    {{"Time", "hrrpum"}, {"Time", "hrrpum"}}, 
>    {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}, 
>    {{4.21, 0.0335006}, {4.21, 0.0416246}}}

You need to remove that nesting by using `Flatten`.

> {{"s", "kW/kg", "s", "kW/kg"}, {"Time", "hrrpum", "Time", 
>     "hrrpum"}, {0., 0., 0., 0.}, {4.21, 0.0335006, 4.21, 0.0416246}}

And the contents of the exported file:

`s,kW/kg,s,kW/kg
Time,hrrpum,Time,hrrpum
0.,0.,0.,0.
4.21,0.033500582,4.21,0.041624561`